# Add Feed to Nuget in Visual Studio

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, manage-nuget-packages

ENGLISH
Hey guys,
My boss sent this on the general channel today:
"Adjust your nuget to the following feed:
https://.....azure.....artifacts....nuget....index.json"

Does anyone have any idea where I go to solve this thing?

Grateful,

I tried to put it here at this stop, but I don't know if that's it

==================================================================
PORTUGUESES
Fala pessoal,
meu chefe mandou no canal geral hoje isso aqui:
"Ajustem o nuget de vcs pro seguinte feed:
https://.....azure.....artefatos....nuget....index.json"

Alguem tem ideia de onde eu mexo pra resolver essa treta?

Grato,

Tentei colocar aqui nessa parada, mas não sei se é isso

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oko7q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step you add the Nuget Feed to Visual Studio is correct.

You can add the Nuget feed to Visual Studio Package Sources.

[image]

Then you will be able to install the package from the Nuget Feed.

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Set up Nuget Feed in  Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#2-set-up-visual-studio)